# PyQt4：Can‘t Open My Dialog When I Write My First Code

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I want to build a dialog with the PyQt4.My compile envirenment is Qt4,Python2 and PyQt4.
I have done something for my job.
1.I complete my UI with Qt Designer and the ui file named dialog.ui.
2.I use the command "pyuic -o ui_dialog.py dialog.ui" to make the python file named ui_dialog.py.
the code of ui_dialog.py is

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'dialog.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt4 UI code generator 4.11.4
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Dialog"))
        Dialog.resize(516, 378)
        self.verticalLayoutWidget = QtGui.QWidget(Dialog)
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 13, 501, 361))
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayoutWidget"))
        self.verticalLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayout"))
        self.label_recieve = QtGui.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.label_recieve.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_recieve"))
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label_recieve)
        self.textBrowser_recieve = QtGui.QTextBrowser(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.textBrowser_recieve.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("textBrowser_recieve"))
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.textBrowser_recieve)
        self.label_send = QtGui.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.label_send.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_send"))
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label_send)
        self.textEdit_send = QtGui.QTextEdit(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.textEdit_send.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("textEdit_send"))
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.textEdit_send)
        self.horizontalLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("horizontalLayout"))
        spacerItem = QtGui.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout.addItem(spacerItem)
        self.pushButton_send = QtGui.QPushButton(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_send.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_send"))
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_send)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout)

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "chat", None))
        self.label_recieve.setText(_translate("Dialog", "recieve", None))
        self.label_send.setText(_translate("Dialog", "send", None))
        self.pushButton_send.setText(_translate("Dialog", "SEND", None))
```

3.I try to write the main.py file and compile it.
My code of main.py is

```
'''
title:chat dialog
author:CCBANG
virsion:0.1
'''
from PyQt4 import QtCore,QtGui 
import sys
from ui_dialog import *

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class ChatDialog(QtGui.QDialog):
        def __init__(self,parent=None):
                QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self,parent)                
                self=Ui_Dialog()

if __name__=='__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myqq=ChatDialog()
    myqq.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

In the main.py ,I don't know how to write "setupUI()" in the "Class ChatDialog"

How can i finish my code ? I would be happy if you can help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this method of using Qt Designer created python files, generally, your class will inherit the `Ui_Dialog` class.

```
class ChatDialog(QtGui.QDialog, Ui_Dialog):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self, parent)                
        self.setupUi(self)
```

Sometimes, people won't inherit, but will assign it to an attribute of the class:

```
class ChatDialog(QtGui.QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self, parent)                
        self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I have known the two ways of inherit from your answer.