# Update GUI at different time interval in QT

Tags: python, c++, multithreading, qt, pyqt

I want to know how to update the GUI at different time interval in QT, the best is that I could control the time intervals. I know QTimer could update GUI at the same time interval but I need to control the time intervals and set them to be different values.

Do I need to use multithreading?

I tried pyqt but Failed, please see "[ui_mainwindow' object has no attribute 'connect'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37007346/ui-mainwindow-object-has-no-attribute-connect)"

Comment: seems like you use pyqt , why are you tagging your question with `c++`?

Comment: Please be more specific.

Comment: @Mike am a C++ Programmer. But I am learning pyqt. Either way is fine for me.

Comment: @Fabio For instance, I want to update the Qtlabel content to be image1 from time t0 to t1, image2 from time t1 to t2, ... , imagen from time t(n-1) to t(n).

Comment: Do you have available code for the similar problem?

Comment: What is determining the time intervals?  Can you just listen for the events that are triggering the update and update based off those events?

Comment: @BrendanAbel the time intervals are set in a setting file, for instance, protocol.txt in "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37007346/ui-mainwindow-object-has-no-attribute-connect". The problem is how to listen for these events? QTimer or something else?

Comment: If it's in a settings file, they it's not really a variable time interval, right?  As in, once you read the interval value from the settings file, the interval isn't going to change?

Comment: @BrendanAbel Once the time intervals are read, they would not change.

Comment: @BrendanAbel the setting file is like this: image1.bmp t0 to t1; image2.bmp t1 to t2; ...; imagen.bmp t(n-1) to t(n). So the time intervals are different at each step.

Comment: @BrendanAbel sorry for the confusion

Comment: Are you trying to animate a widget with different images?  This sounds like a classic [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: @BrendanAbel Yes. it seems that I want to animate the widget. Do you know how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I would implement it, in your `MainWindow`'s class, define a slot that sets the `QLabel` to the next image:

```
void MainWindow::NextImage(){
    switch(currentImageNo){
    case 0:
        //set 1st image
        break;
    case 1:
        //set 2nd image
        break;
    case 2:
        //set 3rd image
        break;
    ...
    }
    timer.setInterval( /*your desired new interval based on currentImageNo*/  );
    currentImageNo++;
    //in order to loop back to the first image after the last image is shown
    currentImageNo= currentImageNo % numberOfImages; 
}
```

in your `MainWindow`'s constructor, create a `QTimer` with your desired interval and connect its `timeout()` signal to the `NextImage` slot defined above

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(){
    ...
    timer= new QTimer(this);
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(NextImage()));
    timer.setSingleShot(false);
    timer.setInterval(5000); //5 secs for first image
    timer.start();
    NextImage(); //to load the first image initially
}
```

remember to declare and initialize `currentImageNo`, `numberOfImages` and `timer` as members of your `MainWindow` class.

Comment: timer is a member for class MainWindow?

Comment: do you have whole set of code?

Comment: it seems it is working! do you have pyqt version of this code? Thanks for you code again.

Comment: @Feng , yes `timer`, `currentImageNo` and `numberOfImages` are all members in class `MainWindow`